# Do I need to re-check my luggage in Montreal?

Tags: luggage

In a few weeks I am flying Boston -> Montreal -> Munich -> St Petersburg (Russia). Do I need to pick up my luggage, go thru Canadian customs and re-check the luggage in Montreal?

Comment: Are all parts of the on the same ticket?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the ticket and the airline. To be safe I would contact the airline and ask. Canadian airports do not offer international transit, i.e. you will have to enter and exit Canada. Check Visa requirements for your nationality

See http://www.admtl.com/en/guide/connecting-flights

scroll all the way down.